# using maven3 plugin for a maven2 build

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, wildfly

I have an application that uses maven 2.2.1 for building. I want to use a plugin that needs maven3 to run during deploy phase of build. Is this possible. Just want to know if someone solved this scenario in a unique way.

Comment: If the plugin needs Maven 3 you can't use it in Maven 2.2.1. Apart from that Maven 2.2.1 is EoL see here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201503.mbox/%3C20150320213920.6AE4B17423%40minotaur.apache.org%3E

Comment: I believe switching to Maven 3 for your application build will be easiest.   Maven3 is mostly compatible with Maven 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to use different Maven installations for different phases or convert everything to Maven3.

Having just converted my build process to Maven3, there is one huge gotcha in Maven3: version ranges on snapshots are totally mucked up.  There was an attempt to rectify version weirdness in Maven2 and instead broke Maven3.  Version ranges with release artifacts work fine, just not snapshot, so something to beware of.

Comment: Can you plese elaborate on using diff maven installations ?

Comment: If I start a build with maven2, how can i change it to use maven3 for deploy phase alone ?

Comment: The reason we didn't go to Maven3 earlier was because snapshot version ranges don't work, so we changed all our build artifacts to be be release and Maven3 handles release ranges just fine.  We have some servers which Maven2 has problems with release ranges, but it's not consistent and appears to be a lesser bug in Maven2.  For the most part, once we moved to release artifacts, either Maven2 or Maven3 worked fine with the existing POMs (including using the M2 plugins with M3, probably not a great idea, but it helps our migration.